# A function that takes an argument and returns a function that returns that argument

Tags: javascript, scope

I am trying to wrap my brains around the fact that `something` equals the value of the returned anonymous function value. I thought with scoping it wouldn't have had access to the functions variables.

So how does calling `something` give you the value of 3?

```
 function somefun (x){
     return function(){
         return x;
     }
 }

 var something = somefun (3);
 something();
 //3
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: No, there is no scope issue here. I suggest reading a good article about javascript scope/closures.

Comment: Well, i know that `x` doesn't know anything outside of `somefun` so how does `something` now have access to a variable inside of `sunfun`

Comment: @JamieHutber As I wrote, read a good article about the issue. You simply have a wrong conception of how/why this is working.

Comment: see rockets answer :) I've read many a good books. Among them mr Douglas's good parts.

Comment: just like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629891/functions-that-return-a-function-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions are just objects, like anything else.  Functions can be assigned to variables.

So `somefun` returns a function, which is assigned to `something`.  Thus, `something` is a function.

So, when `something()` is ran, it returns a value, because it's a function.

That function is called a "closure".  It keeps a reference to the `x` value, which is why it's returned to you.

Comment: so it runs the function, cool. argh pants. Makes sense now, as you gave the function to a variable. ekk i knew this. I just had a brain fart!