# JavaScript Functions that return function

Tags: javascript

I was solving a puzzle on JS and I found this code:

```
var xx = (function () {
    var e = 0;
    return function () { return e++ }
})();
```

It was asked what will be the value of xx.

I've googled about funcitons that return function, but could not find anything helpful, I'm not pretty familiar with functions that return function. Please help.

Comment: Is this the answer you look for? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629891/functions-that-return-a-function-javascript

Comment: @Eduardo help with explaining the functions that return function and what will be the value of xx

Comment: @VisioN I don't think both are same questions sir :)

Comment: [Functions in JavaScript are objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), so you can return a function just like returning an object.

Comment: xx will have the reference of the function inside the main function including the referencing environment,that means the value of variable e will be retained

Comment: i think the answer is 1

Comment: The value of `xx` will be a function which returns the value of `e` and increments it on every call.

Comment: It is just an example for closure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's decompose the statements in its constituents:

```
var xx =(function(){var e = 0; return function(){return e++}})();
```

1. `var e = 0;`
   *assign 0 to e*
2. `return function(){return e++;}`

   return a function **f** which:

   2.1 *return the value of e*

   2.2 *increment e by 1*
3. `var xx = function(){var e = 0; return function(){return e++}})();`

   assign to xx the function `f(){ return e++}` with scope `[e=0]`
4. `xx();`

   Exec the function f:

   4.1 *return the value of e* // 0

   4.2 *increment e by one* // e = 1

   4.3 *`xx` is now the function `f(){ return e++;`} with scope `[e=1]`*

So, `xx` is the function which return the internal value of `e` (starting from **0**) and increment `e` by one.

IF you call `xx();` another time, you'll get:

```
xx(); // returns 1
xx = f(){ return e++;}[e=2] // returns 2 and increment e by one
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this detailed explanation. could you please refer any book or link so that I can see this in more depth. :)

Comment: I used knowledge in *Computability* and *Semantic of Programming Languages* studied at uni. :)

Answer (score 3):

yes, it is returning function, and every time you execute this function xx(); it will return an incremented value

`alert( xx() );` //will alert 0

`alert( xx() );` //will alert 1

`alert( xx() );` //will alert 2

Hope this answers the question

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects; that is, they can be passed around and assigned to variables like anything else. So in your case `xx` is simply a reference to the inner function which can be called, passed around further etc.

One benefit of doing so means you can implement private variables like in your example. By defining `e` inside the outer function, and referencing it inside the inner function, the inner function retains that reference to `e` even after it is returned. This allows you to call

```
xx();
xx();
xx();
```

which will increment and return the value of `e` each time. You can't override this variable since there's no public reference to it.