# Basic Javascript: Functions that Return Functions

Tags: javascript

This is a very basic javascript question:

after defining a function:

```
function a(){
    alert("A!");
    return function(){
        alert("B!")
    };
}
```

If i call the function:

```
a();
```

Only "A!" is alert;
But if i recreate a new function:

```
var newFunc = a();
newFunc();
```

Both "A!" and "B!" are alerted.

Can someone explain why?
Millions THX!!

**This is extracted from p78, Object-Oriented JavaScript, Stoyan Stefanov, PACKT PUBLISHING**

Comment: What part don't you understand?  Calling `a()` creates a function, but doesn't call it.  You can then call the function that `a()` created, but  just calling `a()` doesn't do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple:

```
function a()
{
    alert("A!");
    return function()
    {
        alert("B!");
    };
}
a();
```

In this case, you invoke `a`, and its function body alerts `A!`, and then *returns* a function. The return value (the function that alserts B) is simply ignored.

When you write

```
var newF = a();
newF();
```

The returned function is assigned to `newF`, if you invoke that function, then, via this variable, you can alert B. To do it all in one go, you could easily write:

```
(a())();
```

Comment: May i ask what the parenthesis around a() mean?
Does it mean the return of a() or function of a()?

Comment: @user2988464: They're optional, but they're there for clarity. Those parentheses are used as the grouping operator. It tells JS to _first_ evaluate the `a()` function call, which evaluates to the return value of that function... the return value being `function(){alert('B!');}` is then invoked... `(a())())` == `(function(){alert('B!');})();` == `alert('B')`

Answer (score 4):

Calling the following will execute both alerts:

```
a()();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pKLNW/

---

Your function, `a`, is being executed, and returning a function. But you are not executing that returned function.

In your second example, that's exactly what you are doing, but spread across two lines (hence why you have two `()` in your code).

Answer (score 0):

The return value is just that -- a *return* value. It is not executed.

Try this for fun:

```
a = a();
a();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first call a(); you are calling the function and it returns another function. But you do not call it.
In the second example, you call the function and store the return-value (the function it returns) in a variable, then call that, which will call the function that was returned.

```
function a() {
  alert("A!"); //This will be called when the function a is called.
  //After the alert another function is returned:
  return function(){
    //and if this function is called, it will:
    alert("B!");
  }
}

a(); //Calls a, but do nothing with return value.  

a()(); //Calls a and directly calls the return value after.  

var b = a(); //Calls a and stores return value in variable 'b'
b(); //calls 'b', which is the return value of 'a'.
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly obvious.

The return value of the function is not executed, but rather returned. Anything before the return statement will of course be executed.

So essentially, the code: `var newFunc = a();` assigns the return value of the function `a()` (in this case an anonymous function) to `newFunc`. Thus, calling `newFunc()` will execute the returned anonymous function.

You can force the returned function to run at assignment time using `var newFunc = a()();`, which assigns the return value of the anonymous function to `newFunc` (in this case `null`, and the alert running).

Answer (score 0):

Your first example, `a()`, executes the `a` function, which executes an alert function and returns the function `b` (but does not execute it).

The second example, `var newFunc = a()`, executes `a`, and saves it's value to the variable `newFunc`, meaning it is now equal to `b`.  Then you execute newFunc, and it alerts 'B!'.

Answer (score 0):

When called, a does two things:

1. alerts 'A!'
2. creates a function that alerts 'B!' when called and also returns that function.

Your first example, `a()` is a call to `a`, so it alerts 'A!', creates a function that alerts 'B!' when called returns that function and discards it (because the returned value is not used).

Your second example, `var newFunc = a()` is similar to the first one: it's a call to `a`, alerts 'A!', creates a(nother) function that alerts 'B!', returns the function and the returned value is assigned to `newFunc`. Now `newFunc` is a reference to a function that alerts 'B!'.

Finally the last line of code `newFunc();` calls the function that alerts 'B!'.

Answer (score 0):

when you do:

```
var newFunc = a();
```

function a execute,so "A!" alerted, and function a return value assign to variable newFunc:

`newfunc = function(){
    alert("B!");
}`

so when you execute newfunc,"B!" alerted.

Reference：
[Functions that return a function - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629891/functions-that-return-a-function-javascript)