# Using some, but still need to use the index of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently have a function that allows me to test if something a piece (for connect 4) is in an array, as well as 1, 2, and less respectively. If all 4 numbers are in the array are present, then it returns true. This works.

What I am trying to do is make it so I can use .some, so I can test if the array contains any cases of having a number, and again 3, 2, and 1 less than the number tested.

Right now it will test an individual piece, but I don't know how to get it to grab onto the array to check the index of the individual element it is testing.
Thank you for any responses/Ideas.

```
const testPieces = [1, 2, 3, 4]

const fourInARow = function(piece, array) {
  for (var i = piece; i >= piece - 3; i--) {
    if (array.indexOf(i) === -1) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}
testPieces.some(fourInARow) // The piece that I don't know how to make work
```

Comment: I've read this a few times and I still don't get what you're asking. Imagine that we don't know anything about your project and try again. Provide sample input/output for your imaginary function `some` with explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.some` on your `testPieces` array will pass in each element of the array to the `fourInARow` function as the `piece` argument. It will not pass in your second `array` argument.

You need to provide a function to the `.some` call that already knows about the array for testing. You can do this by returning a [function from the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629891/) e.g.

```
const fourInARow = function(array) {
  return function(piece) {
    for (var i = piece; i >= piece - 3; i--) {
      if (array.indexOf(i) === -1) {
        return false
      }
    }
    return true
  };
}
```

The array you are testing can now be passed to the `.some` call like this;

```
testPieces.some(fourInARow([1,2]));
```

The returned function has created a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) which retains a reference to the test array `[1,2]` which is then compared to the `piece` argument supplied by the call to `.some`.

Comment: Thank you sir! I appreciate the response. I got it to work with another for loop using this as a callback, but I will still try out your solution still, because it is a lot cleaner than what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering why not flip the logic to start from the other side and use instead of `some` `every` with `includes`?

```js
const testPieces = [1, 2, 3, 4]

const inARow = (arr, base) => arr.every((x) => base.includes(x))

console.log(inARow([4,3,1,2], testPieces))
console.log(inARow([5,2,1], testPieces))
```

It becomes one line, it does not care about the order etc. Let me know if I am missing something ...