# How to return function in another function, please?

Tags: javascript

May someone help me with the following code, please. I try to return a function result in another function: `alert("Your email is: " /*+ email of the user*/);`

## Spiritueux Wines and Liquors

```
<script>
    function check_user_age() {
        if (age_of_user() < 18)
            alert("You are too young to buy alcohol.");
    }

    function age_of_user() {
        var age = prompt("What is your age?");
        return age;
    }

    function check_user_mail() {
        if (email_of_user().includes("@"))
            alert("Your email is: " /*+ email*/);
        else alert("Your email should include an '@' symbol");
    }

    function email_of_user() {
        var email = prompt("What is your email?")
        return email;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Functions that return a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629891/functions-that-return-a-function)

Comment: Something like this `var email = email_of_user(); if (email.includes("@")) { alert("Your email is: " + email); }`