# How to pass argument from parent function to child function

Tags: javascript

I have a kinda strange task: create a function that creates other functions (and they will wrap text in HTML tags).

The problem is I can't figure out how to pass parent arguments in child function.

```js
function wrapperBuild(tag) {
  return new Function('text', "return '<' + tag + '>' + text + '<' + tag + '/>");
};

let wrapP = wrapperBuild("p");

console.log(wrapP('some text'));

//expected output: <p>some text</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to call it.

And also you should use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) rather than joining strings.

#### 1

```js
function wrapperBuild(tag) {
  return function (text) {
    return `<${tag}>${text}</${tag}>`;
  };
}

let wrapP = wrapperBuild("p");

console.log(wrapP("some text"));
```

#### 2

```js
function wrapperBuild(tag) {
  return function (text) {
    return `<${tag}>${text}</${tag}>`;
  };
}
let p = wrapperBuild("p")("some text");

console.log(p);

// OR - console.log(wrapperBuild("p")("some text"));
```

#### 3

You can simplify it more by using arrow functions...

```js
const wrapperBuild = (tag) => (text) => `<${tag}>${text}</${tag}>`;

console.log(wrapperBuild("p")("some text"));
```

---

**Some useful links:**

- [Documentation of Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Functions that return a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629891/functions-that-return-a-function)
- [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

Try to return a new function that takes `text` and returns `html`. I've used [arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) function

**Using arrow function**

```js
function wrapperBuild(tag) {
  return (text) => {
    return `<${tag}> ${text} </${tag}>`;
  };
}

const fn = wrapperBuild("h1");
console.log(fn("hello world"));
```

**Using old school function**

```js
function wrapperBuild(tag) {
  return function(text){
    return `<${tag}> ${text} </${tag}>`;
  };
}

const fn = wrapperBuild("h1");
console.log(fn("hello world"));
```

Comment: it works, but im confused with syntax tho :)

Comment: @Johny1995QQ I'm doing exactly what you're doing like returning a function(arrow function in this case), which accepts an argument `text`. So this function `fn` will run and print the result. But you must be wondering about tag, Where does it come. It would come from `closure`