# How to return a function inside of a function? (like p5.js createVector)

Tags: javascript, function, return

```
function createVector(_x, _y, _z) {
 if (_x == undefined) {
  _x = 0;
 }

 if (_y == undefined) {
  _y = 0;
 }

 if (_z == undefined) {
  _z = 0;
 }

 function add(_addX, _addY, _addZ) {
  numX += _addX;
  numY += _addY;
  numZ += _addZ;
 }

 let numX = _x;
 let numY = _y;
 let numZ = _z;

 return {
  x: numX,
  y: numY,
  z: numZ,
  add()
 };
}
```

so far im getting an error that says Unexpected token '}'
im really trying to just get a recreation of the p5.js
createvector() method as I am creating my own library for personal use.
Any help would be much appreciated - Jack

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Functions that return a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629891/functions-that-return-a-function)

Comment: Note that if running in an ES6 environment you can set default argument values as `function createVector(_x=0, _y=0, _z=0) {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to emulate a constructor pattern, make the following adjustments to follow the pattern.

The purpose of adding the `add` function to the prototype is that if you add it to the `createVector` object like you have now, every new instance of `createVector` will have its own instance of that function as well. Adding it to the prototype ensures that only one copy of the function exists.

```js
function createVector(_x, _y, _z) {
  if (_x == undefined) {
    _x = 0;
  }

  if (_y == undefined) {
    _y = 0;
  }

  if (_z == undefined) {
    _z = 0;
  }
  this.x = _x;
  this.y = _y;
  this.z = _z;
}

createVector.prototype.add = function(x, y, z) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    this.z += z;
}

var vec = new createVector(1, 2, 3);
console.log(vec);
vec.add(2, 3, 4);
console.log(vec);
```

You could even create an add function that takes another vector as an argument:

```js
function createVector(_x, _y, _z) {
  if (_x == undefined) {_x = 0;}
  if (_y == undefined) {_y = 0;}
  if (_z == undefined) {_z = 0;}
  this.x = _x;
  this.y = _y;
  this.z = _z;
}

createVector.prototype.add = function(vec) {
  this.x += vec.x;
  this.y += vec.y;
  this.z += vec.z;
}

var vec1 = new createVector(1, 2, 3);
var vec2 = new createVector(2, 3, 4);

console.log(vec1);

vec1.add(vec2);
console.log(vec1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between passing a function and invoking a function. This should give you what you want:

```
 return {
   x: numX,
   y: numY,
   z: numZ,
   add
 };
```

Or more explicitly:

```
 return {
   x: numX,
   y: numY,
   z: numZ,
   add: add
 };
```

And to invoke this method, you might do something like this:

```
const myVector = createVector(5,7,9);
const resultOfAddition = myVector.add(1,2,3);
```

You could even dereference, if you don't need the intermediary value:

```
const myVectorAddition = createVector(5,7,9).add(1,2,3);
```

Comment: Now Im not getting an error but after I console.log() myVector it still says '{x: 5, y: 7, z: 9, add: ƒ}'

Comment: ```return {
   x: numX,
   y: numY,
   z: numZ
  };
```
I tried this and it kinda works but it still doesnt chagne the original values

Answer (score 0):

```
just replace your

return {
    x: numX,
    y: numY,
    z: numZ,
    add()
}; 

to

return {
    x: numX,
    y: numY,
    z: numZ,
    add,
};
```

Comment: The values dont change they stay the original

Comment: Maybe this answer is right, but could you extend the example code written in the question to help.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.