# I don't know the difference

Tags: javascript, function

I've just started learning about function. and here is what gives me difficulty.

```js
const Func = () => {
  return () => {
    console.log('hello');
  };
};

const innerFunc = Func();

innerFunc(); // 1.

Func(); //2.
```

I don't understand why 'hello' doesn't show up on console trying with 2.

Aren't both innerFunc and Func names of function?

I don't know the difference between them.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: `Func()` returns another function `() => {console.log('hello')}`, so when you call `Func()` and assign the result to innerFunc, innerFunc then holds a reference to this second function. (`innerFunc = () => {console.log('hello')}`) see: [Functions that return a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629891/functions-that-return-a-function)

Comment: You are returning a function from a function, so you have to use `Func()();`

Comment: Please put some effort into formulating a descriptive title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Func()` returns a function which will not be executed until you run the result with `()` like you are doing with `1.`.
By doing `const innerFunc = Func();`, you are assigning the function returned from `Func` into `innerFunc`. So to call it, you need to run it like this: `innerFunc()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your function 'Func' returns another function from inside, so when you call Func(), then it will return another function which you named as 'innerFunc' and calling innerFunc will return the output as hello.

When you try with Just 'Func()', it will just return another function which you returned inside Func.

Answer (score 0):

Starting to learn about functions, just look at

```
const Func = () => {
    console.log('hello');
};

Func(); // logs hello to the console
```

What you have here is a function inside of function, which is more complicated and not necessarily beginner friendly.