# continious functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm learning redux and in this piece of code section there is a continuous function to pass the arguments.
I couldn't understand the logic behinds that because i'm the PHP developer originally and it's unusual there.
would you please explain and simplify that for me?

Here is my selector:

```
export const personBugs = userId => createSelector(
    state => state.entities.bugs,
    bugs => bugs.filter(bug => bug.userId === userId )
)
```

And here is my dispatch:

```
console.log(bugsActions.personBugs(1)(store.getState()));
```

Comment: It's called "currying", not "continuous function".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Functions that return a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629891/functions-that-return-a-function)

Comment: Be careful with most functional features in JavaScript. JavaScript lacks [tail call optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/310974/402322), which makes any kind of recursion quite dangerous.

Comment: @ceving for some reason, only iOS and Safari do https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-proper_tail_calls_(tail_call_optimisation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a curry function or [currying](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors#curry), this is when you want to provide one argument and at a later time provide another argument.

I am not sure why a selector is on your actions object but I'm sure that is a mistake. A selector is usually used in components to get data that the component needs but can also be used in middleware to get state info.

Here is an example of how a selector can be used in a component:

```
const PersonBugs = React.memo(function PersonBugs({
  personId,
}) {
  //here is a way to use the curry
  const bugs = useSelector(personBugs(personId));
  //if this wasn't a curry you have to do
  // const bugs = useSelector((state) =>
  //   personBugs(personId, state)
  // );
  //you could also not memoize the selector if you needed to
});
```

More information about selectors can be found [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors)

Comment: The selector is not in action object. I call it from there. My code is running well but it's the training code and may be different from the real code. Thanks for your answer, that's useful.